# Why is my entire page reloading instead of just the Update Panel reloading?

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

Using master and detail pages, I have a `ScriptManager` in my `MasterPage` and an `UpdatePanel` in my detail page.

The `UpdatePanel` refreshes on a timer tick (every second)

In the `UpdatePanel` is an image which is a live view of an HMI process.

(btw using Chrome) "Normally" everything works fine - the image is refreshed to give a reasonably uptodate view of the HMI and is flicker free, but quite often the whole page shudders as it is refreshed in its entirety.

There's no logic behind it. The page is definitely doing a full refresh - the menu bar at the top contained in the `MasterPage` is also refreshed.

This "shuddering" may go on for several seconds (the page being refreshed every second) and then calms down only to be repeated sometime later on.

Can anyone please explain to me what may be happening?

The following code and screen shots, show the reason for the flicker  - the image, for some reason is not displayed for a split second.

This is how the screen looks immediately prior to refresh (notice the time in the title bar)[image: before screen refresh]

And when it flickers, the main image is missing :[image: Image missing here]

and then a split second later (less than a second) the correct image appears (notice the time in the title bar is one second later).

[image: correct image]
Now this is NOT because the web page is not begin asked to display an image - if no image is returned from the WCF service,a default image is shown instead. For some reason, the webpage is simply not displaying the actual image.  The web page is requested to refresh once a second, but the flicker (it happens very, very quickly) indicates that in between refreshes, the whole page (including top nav bar)is refreshed (minus the image). So it appears, the page is refreshing every 1/2 second.

And this happens on only some PCs every so often (random x seconds). I'm watching the page on a remote machine and this hasn't missed a beat, whilst my PC is frequently experiencing the shakes.

Also the Image ALWAYS flickers in I.E. despite partial rendering.

Code samples:

Master Page

```html
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="PracticonWebMimic.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - Practicon Factory View</title>
    
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
       <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true">
            <Scripts>
                <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <%--Site Scripts--%>
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/">Practicon Factory View</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" id="mimicList" visible="false"
                                 href="~/RestrictedAccess/MimicList.aspx">Views</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" id="mimicListArchive" visible="false"
                                 href="~/RestrictedAccess/MimicList.aspx?archive=<%= DateTime.Now.Ticks %>">Archive Views</a></li>
                       <!-- <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li> -->
                    </ul>
                    <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                        <AnonymousTemplate>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                              <!--  <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Register">Register</a></li> -->
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Login">Log in</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </AnonymousTemplate>
                        <LoggedInTemplate>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li>
                                    <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/" OnLoggingOut="Unnamed_LoggingOut" />
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </LoggedInTemplate>
                    </asp:LoginView>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container body-content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">

            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - Practicon Factory View</p>
                <asp:Label  id="lbError" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Details Page

```html
<%@ Page Title="Factory View" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MimicDetails.aspx.cs" Inherits="PracticonWebMimic.MimicDetails" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="TimePicker" Namespace="MKB.TimePicker" TagPrefix="MKB" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
   
     <link href="/Content/PrBlueTable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.ui.timepicker.addon/1.4.5/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.ui.timepicker.addon/1.4.5/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css">
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.ui.timepicker.addon/1.4.5/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
            prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
            prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);
        });

        function InitializeRequest(sender, args) { }
        function EndRequest(sender, args) {
            // after update occur on UpdatePanel re-init the DatePicker 
            $('.ui-datepicker').datetimepicker({
                inline: true,
                showOtherMonths: true,
                showOn: 'focus',
                showButtonPanel : true,
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                nextText: ">>",
                prevText : "<<",
                timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss",
                dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
            });
        }
</script>

    <asp:FormView ID="mimicDetail" runat="server"
            ItemType="PracticonWebMimic.Models.Mimic" SelectMethod ="GetMimic"
            RenderOuterTable="false">

            <ItemTemplate>
                    <div>
                            <h2>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblActive_MimicDetails" runat="server"  Visible="true"/>

                                <%#:Item.MimicName %>


                            </h2>
                          
                           
                    </div>
                    <br />
                  <table>
                              <tr>  
                                    <td>
                                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upMimic_MimicDetails" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"  ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
                                                 <ContentTemplate>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lbConditionName_MimicDetails" runat="server" CssClass="btn-primary" Visible="False"/>
                                                      <asp:Panel ID="pnMimic" runat="server" style="margin-bottom: 2px">
                                                                     <%-- Mimic Image ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --%>
                                                                     <img id="imMimic_MimicDetails" runat="server" src="./Assets/Images/running.jpg"/>
                                                                    
                                                     </asp:Panel>
                                                     <br />
                                                     <h4><asp:Label  id="lbDirection_MimicDetails" runat="server" CssClass="btn-default"  Text=""></asp:Label> </h4>
                                                           <%-- Action Buttons starts here ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --%>
                                                        <asp:Table class="tbActionButtonBar"  runat="server"  CssClass="prTable">
                                                                    <asp:TableRow >
                                                                        <asp:TableCell>

                                                                                <asp:Table class="tbActionButtonBar"  runat="server">

                                                                                        <asp:TableRow >
                                                                                                <asp:TableCell >
                                                                                                        <asp:ImageButton id="btnRestart_MimicDetails" runat="server" onclick="imgRestart_Click" Width="50" ToolTip="Restart playback from beginning." />
                                                                                                        <asp:ImageButton id="btnStop_MimicDetails" runat="server"  onclick="imgStop_Click" Width="50" ToolTip="Stop playback and show the LIVE Factory View." />
                                                                                                        <asp:ImageButton id="btnRewind_MimicDetails" runat="server"  onclick="imgRewind_Click" Width="50" ToolTip="Rewind the animation" />
                                                                                                        <asp:ImageButton id="btnPlay_MimicDetails" runat="server" onclick="imgPlay_Click" Width="50" ToolTip="Start playback of animation from current time." />
                                                                                                        <asp:ImageButton id="btnFForward_MimicDetails" runat="server" onclick="imgFForward_Click" Width="50" ToolTip="Fast-forward through animation." />
                                                                                                        <asp:ImageButton id="btnPause_MimicDetails" runat="server" onclick="imgPause_Click" Width="50" ToolTip="Pause playback of animation." />
                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                </asp:TableCell>

                                                                                                <asp:TableCell> 
                                                                                                      <asp:ImageButton id="btnTrends_MimicDetails" runat="server"  Width="50" ToolTip="Show the Trends for the current Factory View" />
                                                                                                 </asp:TableCell>

                                                                                                 <asp:TableCell>
                                                                                                     <asp:ImageButton id="btnConditionMonitoring_MimicDetails" runat="server"  Width="50" ToolTip="View Condition Monitoring for this Factory View." />
                                                                                                </asp:TableCell>
                                                                                            
                                                                                                <asp:TableCell>
                                                                                                            <h5><asp:Label ID="lbStatus_MimicDetails" runat="server"  CssClass="btn-default" Text=""></asp:Label></h5>
                                                                                                </asp:TableCell>
                                                                                            
                                                                                                 <asp:TableCell>
                                                                                                            <h5><asp:Label ID="lbSession_MimicDetails" runat="server"  CssClass="btn-default" Text=""></asp:Label></h5>
                                                                                                </asp:TableCell>

                                                                                                <asp:TableCell>
                                                                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnSession_MimicDetails" runat="server" Text="Reconnect" CssClass="btn-default" onclick="btnSession_TrendDetails_Click"> </asp:button>
                                                                                                </asp:TableCell >


                                                                                        </asp:TableRow>
                                                                                </asp:Table>
                                                                 </asp:TableCell >

                                                           </asp:TableRow>

                                                        </asp:Table>
                                                     <%-- DateTime control starts here ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --%>
                                                     <asp:Table  id="tbActionDateBar_MimicDetails" runat="server" CssClass="prBlueTable">
                                                                    <asp:TableRow>
                                                                            <asp:TableCell >
                                                                                    <asp:Label Text="FROM   : " runat="server" id="lbFrom_MimicDetails"></asp:Label>
                                                                                    <asp:TextBox type="text" id="txtStartDate_MimicDetails" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtStartDate_MimicDetails_TextChanged" />
                                                                                    <asp:Label  id="lbFromDate_MimicDetails" runat="server"/>
                                                                            </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell>
                                                                                        <asp:CheckBox Text="  End date? " runat="server" id="chkEndDate_MimicDetails" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkEnableEndDate_CheckedChanged"></asp:CheckBox>
                                                                            </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell >
                                                                                        <asp:Label Text="TO    : " runat="server" ID ="lbTo_MimicDetails"></asp:Label>
                                                                            </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell>
                                                                                        <asp:TextBox type="text" id="txtEndDate_MimicDetails" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtEndDate_MimicDetails_TextChanged"/>
                                                                                        <asp:Label  id="lbEndDate_MimicDetails" runat="server"/>
                                                                            </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell>
                                                                                        <asp:CheckBox Text="Auto-restart?" runat="server" id="chkAutoRewind_MimicDetails"  OnCheckedChanged="chkAutorewind_MimicDetails_CheckedChanged"></asp:CheckBox>
                                                                            </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow></asp:Table><asp:Timer ID="tmrMimic_MimicDetails" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="MimicTimer_Tick"> </asp:Timer>
                                                                
                                                     <asp:Label ID="lbServiceResponse_MimicDetails" runat="server" CssClass="btn-default"  Text="" ></asp:Label><br />
                                                     
                                                     <asp:Label  id="lbRefreshRequested_MimicDetails" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                                     
                                                     <asp:Label  id="lbRefreshed_MimicDetails" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br />
                                                     
                                                     <asp:Label ID="lbServiceAddress_MimicDetails" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br/>
                                                     
                                                     <asp:Label ID="lbError_MimicDetails" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

                                                     <asp:Label ID="lbSessionID_MimicDetails" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>


                                                 </ContentTemplate>
                                                <Triggers>
                                                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tmrMimic_MimicDetails" EventName="Tick"/>
                                                   </Triggers>
                                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                    </td>
                            </tr>
                </table>
      
            </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Do you believe the images are just being cached? Since the page and images change so much It could cause a problem.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to **disable hardware acceleration** in the browser.

Comment: Interesting, although I would be curious as to the why behind this.  If anything, it seems like having hardware acceleration enabled should actually PREVENT this from happening, as opposed to causing it to happen.

Comment: Agreed, although unfortunately the problem still occurs when the web page is viewed using a IPad (one) and Safari (build 5)/Dolphin. These * I believe * do not have the hardware acceleration option (introduced in OS v7(?)), so I would have assumed that that the browser would be using software acceleration and therefore no flicker.

Comment: btw, this is where I got the idea from..[link](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1030156)